# Python 3 - ImportError: cannot import name

Tags: python, python-3.x, import

I have a folder:

```
python_scripts/test_import/
|-- __init__.py
|-- m1.py
`-- m2.py
```

Content of `m1.py`:

```
a=3
```

Content of `m2.py`:

```
from . import m1

print(m1.a)
```

When I try to execute `m2.py`, I get the following error:

```
# python3 python_scripts/test_import/m2.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python_scripts/test_import/m2.py", line 1, in <module>
    from . import m1
ImportError: cannot import name 'm1'
```

But if I change import in `m2.py` to this:

```
import m1

print(m1.a)
```

then I see no errors and result of execution is expected:

```
3
```

**Question:**
Why relative import with dot doesn't work here?

Comment: When you're in m2 you're inside the test_import folder of python_scripts. So you have to go TWO levels up to find m1.py, since it's on the same level as python_scripts. One level up would mean the same level as test_import, which is not correct.

Comment: @IrfaanJamarussadiq m1.py and m2.py are both on the same level, they are located in test_import. 
By the way, JohntheTyro gave a definitive answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Error: can't import name m1
Relative import uses the **name** attribute of the imported file to determine the location of the file in the entire package structure, but when the python script is run directly, the **name** of the module is set to **main** instead of the original name of the module. In this way, the relative path cannot be recognized.
So for this you can't just directly using that, your main.py need to be on the top files

```
python_scripts/     
  |-- main.py :from test_import.m import m2
    /test_import/
      _init_.py
      /m/
        |-- __init__.py
        |-- m1.py
        |-- m2.py
```

Or if you insist to do so, you have to change into from .m1 import *

Comment: Don't forget to tip me some reputation, I am earning them currently

Comment: Thanks, your answer cleared everything up. Indeed, for me, it was enough to import a module from an arbitrary file level above. I seem to have a better understanding of how to handle modules correctly.